# How do I commit a file and have everyone else ignore further changes in it?

Tags: git

I have a file named `secret` that I want to first fill in with a non-secret stub, commit, and then add it to `.gitignore` for posterity. However, once `git add`d, it's tracked and ignores `.gitignore`. So I tried `git rm --cached`. Works for me, but now it's removed from the upstream repo. Any way t do this?

Comment: That's not how git works on my PC: I can perfectly well put a file .gitignore  that I've added before, so that changes are ignored afterwards.

Comment: What you should do to keep it simple in this case is add a _sample_ file that you track.... and ignore the _real_ one. People create their real file from the sample one and then they can change it and git won't care.

Comment: The amount of details included in your question is insufficient for troubleshooting.  Please include how you are adding your file to the `.gitignore` and where you have placed this `.gitignore` file in your project.  Also, the path to the file is needed to see if there are any discrepancies

Comment: You can also ask git to ignore a file that is already tracked with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, by the way... but it has to be run on a _per repo_ basis (so everybody will have to run it on their repos when they clone (or on their preexisting local repos) to work).

Comment: @eftshift0 That's not practical.

Comment: @eftshift0 I've seen it done, but it's kind of annoying. I was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: a pretty common way is to commit a `secret.template` file, and to gitignore `secret`. Then let everyone copy `secret.template` to `secret` and edit that file with their values.

Comment: Yes @LeGEC I've seen it, but I didn't know whether it's for historic reasons for example. Okay.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Really? AFAIK it shouldn't work that way, unless you did something along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/184546).